# Integration Karate feature file with jmeter for load testing

Tags: api, jmeter, karate, web-api-testing

I have to run karate feature files containing all the test through jmeter for load testing.
Any ways to convert karate feature file in to jmx file dynamically or any other way to convert these test feature files into jmeter supportive files for load testing.

Comment: and please read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling

Comment: Thanks Peter for the reply. Actually I am looking to run performance test on my already created kaarte tests using Jmeter. Karate -Gatling I have already achieved  as karate Gatling is part of same framework. Need to do similar kind of performance of karate test with jmeter, Also it needs to be automated approach. Hope you have done something around it.

Comment: no I have not ! and by the way I will never do. I really don't understand why if you have something working - that you have to need to re-do it for JMeter. note that there are reasons why Gatling is technically superior to JMeter. if you need to show this comment to somebody who is asking you to do this time-wasting work, please do.